# NoSuchElementException with headless chrome and selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to use headless chrome for our selenium tests and have made the below changes:

```
DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--headless");
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
options.addArguments("window-size=1800x1080");
desiredCapabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```

My test logs into an internal page and then waits for the element to be visible:

```
selenium.waitForElementVisible("xpath=//tr/td/div[@class[contains(., 'x-grid-cell-inner')] and text()='Global Test Merchant 14']");
```

This all works well when i do not have the headless option but i get :

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:  {"method":"xpath","selector":"//tr/td/div[@class[contains(., 'x-grid-cell-inner')] and text()='Global Test Merchant 14']"}
```

when i run the test with --headless.

Chrome Version: 62.0.3202.89
chromeDriver: 2.33.506120
Selenium version: 2.53.0
Windows 7

Comment: so how the problem could be solved?

Comment: Same issue for me with python. It's OK in normal mode mode but throws in headless.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, my mistake was because i was making driver.get("localhost:...") instead of driver.get("http://localhost:...")

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when I ran headless as well, my project while running headless continue to trigger the NoSuchElementException and the default-browser-check was getting in the way, try adding these arguments. Just a thought

```
chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--test-type");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-first-run");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-default-browser-check");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
```

Comment: I tried the above solution but i still get the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

As you are seeing **NoSuchElementException** you can consider using the `xpath` along with a waiter for the element to be visible as follows :

```
//tr/td/div[@class='x-grid-cell-inner' and contains(., 'Global Test Merchant')]
```

Comment: I have tried with implicit waits but it doesn't work. This problem happens only in headless mode and not otherwise.

Comment: Can you update the question with the relevant _HTML_, your code trial and the error stack trace for further analysis?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

I tried following options and it worked for me.

```
    options.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
    options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
    options.addArguments("--proxy-server='direct://'");
    options.addArguments("--proxy-bypass-list=*");
    options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
    options.addArguments("--headless");
    options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
    options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
    options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
    options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
```

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case I only had to use these 3 arguments to solve the same issue:

```
options.addArguments("--headless");
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
options.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case adding this line (after line where exception shows) helped.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofMillis(500));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).